# OPENCV (Unsupported format or combination formats) SURF

Tags: opencv

anyone familiar with this error? I tested a surf descriptor in real-time. I want to use it for recognition of different species of fish using of this features. Sometimes the program is okay but sometimes it gets an error. The compilation is Build successfully. After the compilation this error show.

[image]

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
using namespace cv;


#define nimg 3


int main()
{
    Mat object =  imread( "D:/galunggong.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat object1 = imread( "D:/sapsap.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat object2 = imread( "D:/bisugo.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    // Mat object3 = imread( "4.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    //Mat object4 = imread( "5.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

if( !object.data )
{
    std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
  if( !object1.data )
{
    std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
    if( !object2.data )
{
    std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
    return -1;
}


//Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 1000;

SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object1;
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object2;
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object3;
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object4;

detector.detect( object,  kp_object );
detector.detect( object1, kp_object1 );
detector.detect( object2, kp_object2 );


//Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat des_object;
Mat des_object1;
Mat des_object2;


extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );
extractor.compute( object1, kp_object1, des_object1 );
extractor.compute( object2, kp_object2, des_object2 );


FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
 CvCapture* cap = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
cvSetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cvSetCaptureProperty( cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240 );

namedWindow("Good Matches");

std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

//Get the corners from the object
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

char key = 'a';
int framecount = 0;
Mat frame;



 Mat des_image, img_matches;

 char vect[nimg];
 char contor;
 char ok, ko;



while (1)
{

        frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);

    if (framecount < 5)
    {
        framecount++;
        continue;
    }

    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;

    std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
    std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches1;
    std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches2;

    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches1;
    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches2;


    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    Mat H;
    Mat image;




    cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    detector.detect( image, kp_image );
    extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );



    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);



    //  printf("d \n");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    contor=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS
SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int)
matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }

    vect[contor]=good_matches.size();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    contor=1;
    matcher.knnMatch(des_object1, des_image, matches1, 2);


    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches1.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS
SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches1[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches1[i][1].distance)) && ((int)
matches1[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches1[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches1.push_back(matches1[i][0]);
        }
    }

    vect[contor]=good_matches1.size();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    contor=2;
    matcher.knnMatch(des_object2, des_image, matches2, 2);


    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches2.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS
SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches2[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches2[i][1].distance)) && ((int)
matches2[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches2[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches2.push_back(matches2[i][0]);
        }
    }
    vect[contor]=good_matches2.size();
////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    /*
    contor =3; 
    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches3, 2);


    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches3.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS
SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches3[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches3[i][1].distance)) && ((int)
matches3[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches3[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches3.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }
    vect[contor]=good_matches3.size();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    contor=4;
    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches4, 2);


    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches4.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS
SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches4[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches4[i][1].distance)) && ((int)
matches4[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches4[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches4.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }
  vect[contor]=good_matches4.size();

  */
printf("%d %d %d \n ",vect[0],vect[1],vect[2]);

ok=0;
for (contor=1;contor<nimg;contor++)
    if (vect[contor]>vect[contor-1])
        ok=contor;

for (ko=10;ko>3;ko++)
{
if (ok==0 && vect[ok]>ko)
    {printf("Forward \n");
    ko=2;}
else if (ok==1 && vect[ok]>ko)
    {printf("Turn Left \n");
    ko=2;}
else if (ok==2 && vect[ok]>ko)
    {printf("Turn Right \n");
    ko=2;}



}        



    //Show detected matches
    imshow( "Good Matches",frame /*img_matches*/ );

    key = waitKey(1);  
}

}
```

Comment: There are lots of answer in google by the query _"unsupported format or combination of formats" miniflann_. If none of them fits your situation, at least provide source code to reproduce the error.

Comment: almost sure, that that's an empty mat.  start the debugger (F5) let it crash, and slowly move up the stacktrace until you reach your code

Comment: Hello berak

How can I move up the stacktrace ?

I added the code at the top.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SURF cannot find any feature points so it may return an empty descriptor.
You should check the descriptors for data:

`if(des_object.empty()||des_object1.empty()||des_object2.empty())
{
 std::cout<<"Empty descriptor(s)."<<std::endl;
 return -1;
}`